# How to get value from a href tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

so i have webpage called news.php where i show all the website news from database.
i want to make new page to view only single news by news id from database, for example the page is shownews.php

so this is my index.php

```
<?php
include('config/webconf.php');
include('includes/head.php');
include('includes/nav.php');
include('includes/body.php');
include('includes/foot.php');
?>
```

my body.php contain this to modify the url to /?p=pagename :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
  if(file_exists("pages/" . $_GET['p'] . ".php")) {
    include("pages/" . $_GET['p'] . ".php");
  }else{
    include("pages/notfound.php");
  }
}else{
  include("pages/info.php");
}
?>
```

news.php (show all news)

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $webdb);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,title, content, author FROM news");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($newsid, $title, $content, $author);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
  while($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $title." (<a href='/?p=shownews?id=".$newsid."' target='_blank'>view</a>)";
 }
}
```

so in shownews.php i want to get the id from $newsid, but i think cannot get it because of the url is /?p=shownews?id=1 where the url name function will not find **shownews?id=1** (page not found)

so i tried to change /?p=shownews to pages/shownews.php?id=$newsid :

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $webdb);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,title, content, author FROM news");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($newsid, $title, $content, $author);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
  while($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $title." (<a href='pages/shownews.php?id=".$newsid."' target='_blank'>view</a>)";
 }
}
```

now i can get $news id by $_GET function in shownews.php, but the website styles is gone like div/background etc.

my question is, can i get the news id in page shownews.php without changing the url name function?

Comment: `?p=shownews?id` - The 2nd ? should be an ampersand `&`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner To add to your comment: as for all `?` after that come after the first `?` symbol should be an ampersand.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank you! really forgot the use of ampersand.